# "Cumulative difference" function in R

Tags: r, window-functions, cumsum

Is there a pre-existing function to calculate the cumulative difference between consequtive values?

Context: this is to estimate the change in altitude that a person has to undergo in both directions on a journey generated by [CycleStreet.net](http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/v1/journey/).

Reproducible example:

```
x <- c(27, 24, 24, 27, 28) # create the data
```

Method 1: for loop

```
for(i in 2:length(x)){ # for loop way
  if(i == 2) cum_change <- 0
  cum_change <-  Mod(x[i] - x[i - 1]) + cum_change
  cum_change
}
## 7
```

Method 2: vectorised

```
diffs <- Mod(x[-1] - x[-length(x)]) # vectorised way
sum(diffs)

## 7
```

Both seem to work. I'm just wondering if there's another (and more generalisable) implementation in base R or with something like dplyr or [RcppRoll](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/index.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is shorter than what you have:

```
sum(abs(diff(x)))
```

It's equivalent to your second solution, other than using `diff` to compute the diffs, and `abs` instead of `Mod`, as the input is real (no imaginary component).

Comment: R is so awsome - that seemless stringing together of functions reminds me of the unix pipe. which makes me think this is another useful (although less concise) way of representing that: x %>% diff() %>% abs() %>% sum()

Comment: There are some cases where pipes improve readability, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: Agreed -> One can get carried away with pipes!

Comment: Heh. And would that also apply to the maggitr/tidyverse use of ">%%"?

Comment: @42- I'm still not a fan of pipe-all-the-things, but maybe I'll come around.