# After fitting the cumulative distribution in R creating the normal distribution from fitted parameters

Tags: r, math, statistics, curve-fitting, normal-distribution

After successfully fitting my cumulative data with Gompertz function, I need to create normal distribution from fitted function.

This is the code so far:

```
      df <- data.frame(x = c(0.01,0.011482,0.013183,0.015136,0.017378,0.019953,0.022909,0.026303,0.0302,0.034674,0.039811,0.045709,0.052481,0.060256,0.069183,0.079433,0.091201,0.104713,0.120226,0.138038,0.158489,0.18197,0.20893,0.239883,0.275423,0.316228,0.363078,0.416869,0.47863,0.549541,0.630957,0.724436,0.831764,0.954993,1.096478,1.258925,1.44544,1.659587,1.905461,2.187762,2.511886,2.884031,3.311311,3.801894,4.365158,5.011872,5.754399,6.606934,7.585776,8.709636,10,11.481536,13.182567,15.135612,17.378008,19.952623,22.908677,26.30268,30.199517,34.673685,39.810717,45.708819,52.480746,60.255959,69.183097,79.432823,91.201084,104.712855,120.226443,138.038426,158.489319,181.970086,208.929613,239.883292,275.42287,316.227766,363.078055,416.869383,478.630092,549.540874,630.957344,724.43596,831.763771,954.992586,1096.478196),
                 y = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00044816,0.00127554,0.00221488,0.00324858,0.00438312,0.00559138,0.00686054,0.00817179,0.00950625,0.01085188,0.0122145,0.01362578,0.01514366,0.01684314,0.01880564,0.02109756,0.0237676,0.02683182,0.03030649,0.0342276,0.03874555,0.04418374,0.05119304,0.06076553,0.07437854,0.09380666,0.12115065,0.15836926,0.20712933,0.26822017,0.34131335,0.42465413,0.51503564,0.60810697,0.69886817,0.78237651,0.85461023,0.91287236,0.95616228,0.98569093,0.99869001,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999))

library(drc)
fm <- drm(y ~ x, data = df, fct = G.3())

options(scipen = 10) #to avoid scientific notation in x axis

plot(df$x, predict(fm),type = "l", log = "x",col = "blue",
           main = "Cumulative function distribution",xlab = "x", ylab = "y")

points(df,col = "red")

legend("topleft", inset = .05,legend = c("exp","fit")
       ,lty = c(NA,1), col = c("red", "blue"), pch = c(1,NA), lwd=1, bty = "n")


summary(fm)
```

And this is the following plot:
[image]

My idea is now to transform somehow this cumulative fit to the normal distribution.  Is there any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of the `cumdiff` (for lack of a better term). The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209733/cumulative-difference-function-in-r) helped a lot.

## EDIT

```
 plot(df$x[-1], Mod(df$y[-length(df$y)]-df$y[-1]), log = "x", type = "b",  
      main = "Normal distribution for original data", 
      xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
```

yielding:

[image: For original data set]

## ADDITION

In order to get the Gaussian from the `fitted`function:

```
df$y_pred<-predict(fm)
plot(df$x[-1], Mod(df$y_pred[-length(df$y_pred)]-df$y_pred[-1]), log = "x", 
     type = "b", main="Normal distribution for fitted function", 
     xlab = "x", lab = "y")
```

yielding:

[image: Fitted data]

Comment: Okay, so this is the way you created the normal plot from my initial data set and not from the fitting. I will dig in now and see how to do it for fitting eq.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But is there a way to plot actually x values on x-axis instead of Index? I tried but I ended up with an issue of different lengths between `Mod(df$y[-length(df$y)]-df$y[-1])` and `df$x` ...

Comment: yup you're right... I was thinking of that too. Try `str(fm)` and see if you can get some info. I am not that familiar with the package `drc` after all. Right now I can't dive into, but I promise I ll get back to you asap.

Comment: Where you able to manage plotting x-values instead of Index values? I've tried different things but no success. If nothing, I will post that question ...

Comment: Pretty busy week for me.Haven't managed it to get the `df$x`  in x-axis... I 'll leave it as an exercise to the reader

Comment: I think I managed to do it: `plot(df$x[-1], Mod(df$y[-length(df$y)]-df$y[-1]), log="x", type="b")`. This gives me an output that I wanted.

Comment: @numb great! then you can edit the asnwer and add a _new_ plot?

Comment: Will do it asap.

Comment: I will do it tomorrow, not sure what this means. _Suggested edit  queue is full_

Comment: its a rush hour (probably waking up in the US) . No rush. Glad my suggestion helped

Comment: Log scale misled me. If you edit a bit I can reverse my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

While your original intention might be non-parametric, I suggest using parametric estimation method: method of moments, which is widely used for problems like this, because you have a certain parametric distribution (normal distribution) to fit. The idea is quite simple, from the fitted cumulative distribution function, you can calculate the mean (`E1` in my code) and variance (square of `SD` in my code), and then the problem is solved, because normal distribution can be totally determined by mean and variance.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(0.01,0.011482,0.013183,0.015136,0.017378,0.019953,0.022909,0.026303,0.0302,0.034674,0.039811,0.045709,0.052481,0.060256,0.069183,0.079433,0.091201,0.104713,0.120226,0.138038,0.158489,0.18197,0.20893,0.239883,0.275423,0.316228,0.363078,0.416869,0.47863,0.549541,0.630957,0.724436,0.831764,0.954993,1.096478,1.258925,1.44544,1.659587,1.905461,2.187762,2.511886,2.884031,3.311311,3.801894,4.365158,5.011872,5.754399,6.606934,7.585776,8.709636,10,11.481536,13.182567,15.135612,17.378008,19.952623,22.908677,26.30268,30.199517,34.673685,39.810717,45.708819,52.480746,60.255959,69.183097,79.432823,91.201084,104.712855,120.226443,138.038426,158.489319,181.970086,208.929613,239.883292,275.42287,316.227766,363.078055,416.869383,478.630092,549.540874,630.957344,724.43596,831.763771,954.992586,1096.478196),
                 y=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00044816,0.00127554,0.00221488,0.00324858,0.00438312,0.00559138,0.00686054,0.00817179,0.00950625,0.01085188,0.0122145,0.01362578,0.01514366,0.01684314,0.01880564,0.02109756,0.0237676,0.02683182,0.03030649,0.0342276,0.03874555,0.04418374,0.05119304,0.06076553,0.07437854,0.09380666,0.12115065,0.15836926,0.20712933,0.26822017,0.34131335,0.42465413,0.51503564,0.60810697,0.69886817,0.78237651,0.85461023,0.91287236,0.95616228,0.98569093,0.99869001,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999))

library(drc)
fm <- drm(y ~ x, data = df, fct = G.3())

options(scipen = 10) #to avoid scientific notation in x axis

plot(df$x, predict(fm),type="l", log = "x",col="blue", main="Cumulative distribution function",xlab="x", ylab="y")

points(df,col="red")

E1 <- sum((df$x[-1] + df$x[-length(df$x)]) / 2 * diff(predict(fm)))
E2 <- sum((df$x[-1] + df$x[-length(df$x)]) ^ 2 / 4 * diff(predict(fm)))
SD <- sqrt(E2 - E1 ^ 2)
points(df$x, pnorm((df$x - E1) / SD), col = "green")

legend("topleft", inset = .05,legend= c("exp","fit","method of moment")
       ,lty = c(NA,1), col = c("red", "blue", "green"), pch = c(1,NA), lwd=1, bty="n")


summary(fm)
```

[image: CDF]

And the estimation results:

```
## > E1 (mean of fitted normal distribution)
## [1] 65.78474
## > E2 (second moment of fitted normal distribution)
##[1] 5792.767
## > SD (standard deviation of fitted normal distribution)
## [1] 38.27707
## > SD ^ 2 (variance of fitted normal distribution)
## [1] 1465.134
```

Edit: updated method to calculate moments from cdf fitted by `drc`. The function `moment` defined below calculates moment estimation using the moment formula for continuous r.v. `E(X ^ k) = k * \int x ^ {k - 1} (1 - cdf(x)) dx`. These are the best estimation I can get from the fitted cdf. And the fit is not very good when `x` is near zero because of the reason in original datasets as I discussed in comments.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(0.01,0.011482,0.013183,0.015136,0.017378,0.019953,0.022909,0.026303,0.0302,0.034674,0.039811,0.045709,0.052481,0.060256,0.069183,0.079433,0.091201,0.104713,0.120226,0.138038,0.158489,0.18197,0.20893,0.239883,0.275423,0.316228,0.363078,0.416869,0.47863,0.549541,0.630957,0.724436,0.831764,0.954993,1.096478,1.258925,1.44544,1.659587,1.905461,2.187762,2.511886,2.884031,3.311311,3.801894,4.365158,5.011872,5.754399,6.606934,7.585776,8.709636,10,11.481536,13.182567,15.135612,17.378008,19.952623,22.908677,26.30268,30.199517,34.673685,39.810717,45.708819,52.480746,60.255959,69.183097,79.432823,91.201084,104.712855,120.226443,138.038426,158.489319,181.970086,208.929613,239.883292,275.42287,316.227766,363.078055,416.869383,478.630092,549.540874,630.957344,724.43596,831.763771,954.992586,1096.478196),
                 y=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00044816,0.00127554,0.00221488,0.00324858,0.00438312,0.00559138,0.00686054,0.00817179,0.00950625,0.01085188,0.0122145,0.01362578,0.01514366,0.01684314,0.01880564,0.02109756,0.0237676,0.02683182,0.03030649,0.0342276,0.03874555,0.04418374,0.05119304,0.06076553,0.07437854,0.09380666,0.12115065,0.15836926,0.20712933,0.26822017,0.34131335,0.42465413,0.51503564,0.60810697,0.69886817,0.78237651,0.85461023,0.91287236,0.95616228,0.98569093,0.99869001,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999,0.99999999))

library(drc)
fm <- drm(y ~ x, data = df, fct = G.3())

moment <- function(k){
    f <- function(x){
        x ^ (k - 1) * pmax(0, 1 - predict(fm, data.frame(x = x)))
    }
    k * integrate(f, lower = min(df$x), upper = max(df$x))$value
}

E1 <- moment(1)
E2 <- moment(2)
SD <- sqrt(E2 - E1 ^ 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I will dig into this and see how can I deal with the method of moments. I am bit concerned that it doesn't fit nicely in the first part of the graph (somewhere until x = 80). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: So, I tried plotting the normal distribution from your moments and the bad fit in the starting points leads to weird looking normal distribution (because it doesn't reach 0 in first period). This is the code I used:
`y2 <- dnorm(df$x,mean = E1,sd = SD) plot(df$x,y2,type = "b")` 
and this is the [plot](http://imgur.com/a/0ZCWE)

Comment: @numb I found out the problem is because too large SD estimation. And this is because the original `df$x` is dense when x is small but quite sparse when x is large, which results in the problem. I am looking for ways to obtain a better estimation.

Comment: @numb I estimate the parameters `E1`, `E2`, `SD` as the best I can do from the fitted model. The problem you mentioned alleviates a little, but it still exists. It seems that if you fitted your data by `drs` and use normal distribution to refit the fitted data, this kind of problem is somewhat unavoidable, unless you do some manual adjustment.

Comment: @numb Ok, after some detailed investigation, I think I find the root of the problem, it seems like it is in your original data. Let me explain, we all know normal distribution is symmetric, and the center of your original data (where `y = 0.5`) is somewhat near `x = 60`, and you can find out that `x` is around `130` where `y = 0.95`, and the symmetric point of that is `x` around `-10` where `y = 0.05`. All the above is just some rough estimation, but it suggest that your original data is not that symmetric when it comes to points far away from the center, which causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for diving into the problem and explaining the root of the problem. I can't do anything about this data set because it is an experimental measurement. I am afraid that other sets are also similar. I like the idea and approach behind it, shame it doesn't fit.

Comment: @numb I updated my method of calculating moments, the problem still exists. That's the best I can do.

Comment: Thank you for the help and effort!