# R function to add the cumulative difference of a selected column to a DF

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns, cumulative-sum

Lately i have encountered the possibility to add to a given DF the cumulative sum of a selected column with the function: cumsum(your_df$Selected_column).

I was wondering if there is an equivalent function in R, but for the cumulative difference.

So far I have built this function that does the trick, but probably there is a function that I am missing which does the job easier and more efficient, does anybody know it?

An example of my simple function:

```
column_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
column_2 <- c(21000, 23400, 30000)
df_example <- data.frame(column_1, column_2)

cumulative_difference <- function(my_df,column_name)
{
  cumulative_difference=rep(0,nrow(my_df))
  cumulative_difference[1] <- my_df[1,column_name]
  
  for(i in 2:nrow(my_df)){
    cumulative_difference[i] <- my_df[i,column_name]-my_df[i-1,column_name]
  }
  
  my_df["Cumulative_differenced"] <- unlist(cumulative_difference)
  return(my_df)
}


test <- cumulative_difference(my_df=df_example,column_name="column_2")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This page might have the answer you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209733/cumulative-difference-function-in-r

Comment: Hello @Silentdevildoll,
I saw that post before, and the algorithm follows obviously the same logic of the loop that I made, the questions is more: that R include a cleaner function to do this job? 

Like it does with the cumsum() function.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! While there's possibly cleaner functions for calculate cummulative differences, that's a question that can be solved by conducting a diligent web search, as it's not really a conding issue. But if you want to know how to improve your function of troubleshoot issues with it, you might get better answers in SO.